# How to set tag arguments of stereo camera plugin (libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so)?

Tags: stereo-vision, gazebo-camera, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have some questions about how to use "libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so" plugin.

1. what does   tag arguments mean ?
2. Some arguments are both set in  and , for example distortion arguments like  , <...K2> <...K2>, ...<...T2> <...T2> in , as I have already set ..., will they conflicts?
   Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19335/how-to-set-tag-arguments-of-stereo-camera-plugin-(libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so)?/) by [luxiaojun](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5079/luxiaojun/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When you're not sure what the tags do, it's best you check out the plugin's source code.

In this case it's here:
http://docs.ros.org/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__multicamera_8cpp_source.html
But the actual reading of the sdf tags happens here: http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__camera__utils_8cpp_source.html

1. From what I found, the hack_baseline is only used in one spot for the camera projection matrix. I'm not entirely sure what it's for.
2. The tags you listed in your question should not conflict with one another. The tags in the plugin tag apply to the plugin only and do not affect the camera itself in any way.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luxiaojun](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5079/luxiaojun/) on 2018-05-15**:
Raskkii: thank you for your reply. what do you mean "one spot for the camera projection matrix" ?
Why a plugin needs  parameters?
As I am new to this, thank you for your reply.

**Comment by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) on 2018-05-15**:
So the plugin calculates a camera projection matrix (i'm not sure what it is, i just read it from the source code) and one of the values within the matrix uses the hack_baseline value.
From what I can see in the source code, it seems like the distortion parameters are used for camera info only so you might aswell leave those values to 0 or just remove them entirely.

**Comment by [robinshaun](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24558/robinshaun/) on 2020-03-12**:
hackbaseline is the length of baseline, its an important parameter for stereo camera.
see http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html